# angular can not get user data form sessionstorage

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, local-storage, session-storage

sorry about my english.
I use sessionstorage for keeping data. In sessionstorage have data [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYQQL.png)

but in html, not showing data form sessionstorage. when I get only {{currentUser}} in html show like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi4cn.png)
mycode services

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

const USER_KEY = 'auth-user';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenStorageService {
  constructor() { }

  signOut(): void {
   window.sessionStorage.clear();
   }



  public saveUser(user: any): void {
    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(USER_KEY);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(USER_KEY, JSON.stringify(user));
  }

 public getUser(): any {
   const user = window.sessionStorage.getItem(USER_KEY);
    if (user) {
     return JSON.parse(user);
    }

   return {};
   }
 }
```

html

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="currentUser; else loggedOut">
<header class="jumbotron">
  <h3>
    <strong>{{ currentUser.employee_code }}</strong> Profile
  </h3>
</header>
<p>
  <strong>Token:</strong>
  {{ currentUser.accessToken.substring(0, 20) }} ...
  {{ currentUser.accessToken.substr(currentUser.accessToken.length - 20) }}
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Emp:</strong>
  {{ currentUser }}
</p>

</div>
{{ currentUser }}
<ng-template #loggedOut>
  Please login.
</ng-template>
```

and component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TokenStorageService } from '../../../services/token-storage.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-home',
 templateUrl: './home.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
 currentUser: any;
 constructor(private token: TokenStorageService) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.currentUser = this.token.getUser();
   console.log(this.currentUser = this.token.getUser())
  }

}
```

how i can do to use please help me

this image for {{ currentUser|json}}
[{{ currentUser|json}}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHGf3.jpg)

Comment: The attached images are not clearly visible.

Comment: sorry i post new image in comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `TokenStorageService` change `getUser()` method.

```js
   public getUser(): any {
      return JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem(USER_KEY));
   }
```

In HTML you are printing `{{ currentUser }}` Which will be an object. You need to specify the property of object.

Note: If you want to see the object in html use `json` pipe. (`{{ currentUser | json }}`)

Comment: it work but i want to use some value in array when i use {{ currentUser.employee_code }} not work

Comment: I would recommend you to use a single object to store user details in session. So that current user will be an Object instead of an array. before value passed to `saveUser` you should convert this.

Comment: If not user `{{ currentUser[0].employee_code }}` it will work. but do consider converting it into Object.

Comment: i use {{ currentUser[0].employee_code }} but not work too

Comment: I have updated the code. Please check with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

if I could see it correctly in your attached image, It is an array not an object, so you will need to use it like currentUser[0], to check it on your own please use

{{ currentUser | json}} in HTML it will show the exact content.

Comment: it work but i want to use some value in array when i use {{ currentUser.employee_code }} not work

Comment: Yes this will not work because, if you use it directly currentUser.employee_code you are trying to get employee_code  from array directly whereas this propery exist on  object which is present at 0th index.

let currentUser = [{employee_code : 123}]
so when u use currentUser.employee_code you get undefined.
you should use currentUser[0].employee_code.

Comment: i use {{ currentUser[0].employee_code }} but not work too

Comment: could you share a screenshot with the html {{currentUser | json}}

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hi, I have created a similar app with the source code provided by you [stackblitz link here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j1sfvd). I have made some modifications to mimic the login scenario.

You should be able to see the data on the initial load of the data. As the component is being initialized for the first time. But whereas when you change the user with the change user button. Although the session storage data changes. You won't be able to see the new data. In order to see these kinds of dynamic changes, you need to make use of [Observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular)/[Subjects](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject).

Edit 1: The issue here was that the key & value stored in the local storage as stored as strings. So while storing we have to do JSON.Stringify() and JSON.Parse() while extracting back. This is explained in detail [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOd5cTJ6kaA).

Comment: i get data form database this my code in save data                                                                     
                                                                                                                                           
async readWos(emp:any)  {
    this.wosService.read(emp)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
        this.tokenStorage.saveUser(data[0]);
        this.isLoginFailed = false;
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        this.reloadPage();
        },
        err => {
          alert("รหัสพนักงานไม่ถูกต้อง");
        });
  }

Comment: @KittiphobRakyutitham can you fork this [project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j1sfvd) and do similar changes and make your issue reproducible in that project. And add that to the question. So people could help you better.